# Error:global name 'oauth_token' is not defined

Tags: python, django, twitter

I am using **django-social-auth** and **tweepy** in Django to post tweet to Twitter using its api. Login using Twitter works fine but while posting tweet i get this error from views.py : `global name 'oauth_token' is not defined.`  Thanks in advance.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from social_auth.models import UserSocialAuth
import tweepy
from twapp import settings


def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':

        instance = UserSocialAuth.objects.filter(user=request.user).get()
        oauth_access_token = (instance.tokens).get(oauth_token)

        oauth_access_secret = (instance.tokens).get(oauth_token_secret)
        print oauth_access_token
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY, settings.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET)
        auth.set_access_token(oauth_access_token, 'oauth_access_secret')
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        print api.me().name
        api.update_status('Updating using OAuth authentication via Tweepy!')
    return render(request, 'home.html')


def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    return render(request, 'home.html')
```

Comment: You sure it's not supposed to be `oauth_access_secret`? Otherwise, post some code.

Comment: put double quote `.get('oauth_token')`

Comment: oauth_token has no value when you pass it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot the double quote

```
oauth_access_token = (instance.tokens).get('oauth_token')
```